# simple php captcha doesn't display image

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, captcha

I'm  trying to display a captcha image using *simple-php-captcha.php* .It's working fine on my local but on the net it doesn't show the captcha image and I think it's because of my url structure. 
The url of the page is like this `http://test.org/v245/some-url` and when I check the captcha image src , It's Look like this `src="/simple-php-captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.11252600+1451561363"`.

I have tried this `http://test.org/simple-php-captcha.php?_CAPTCHA&t=0.11252600+1451561363` But it doesn't make the captcha image .

What's the problem ? Should I change something in htaccess ?

UPDATE:
This is the code of *simple-php-captcha.php*:

```
<?php
//
//  A simple PHP CAPTCHA script
//
//  Copyright 2013 by Cory LaViska for A Beautiful Site, LLC
//
//  See readme.md for usage, demo, and licensing info
//
function simple_php_captcha($config = array()) {

    // Check for GD library
    if( !function_exists('gd_info') ) {
        throw new Exception('Required GD library is missing');
    }

    $bg_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/backgrounds/';
    $font_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/fonts/';

    // Default values
    $captcha_config = array(
        'code' => '',
        'min_length' => 5,
        'max_length' => 5,
        'backgrounds' => array(
            $bg_path . '45-degree-fabric.png',
            $bg_path . 'cloth-alike.png',
            $bg_path . 'grey-sandbag.png',
            $bg_path . 'kinda-jean.png',
            $bg_path . 'polyester-lite.png',
            $bg_path . 'stitched-wool.png',
            $bg_path . 'white-carbon.png',
            $bg_path . 'white-wave.png'
        ),
        'fonts' => array(
            $font_path . 'times_new_yorker.ttf'
        ),
        'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZabcdefghjkmnprstuvwxyz23456789',
        'min_font_size' => 28,
        'max_font_size' => 28,
        'color' => '#666',
        'angle_min' => 0,
        'angle_max' => 10,
        'shadow' => true,
        'shadow_color' => '#fff',
        'shadow_offset_x' => -1,
        'shadow_offset_y' => 1
    );

    // Overwrite defaults with custom config values
    if( is_array($config) ) {
        foreach( $config as $key => $value ) $captcha_config[$key] = $value;
    }

    // Restrict certain values
    if( $captcha_config['min_length'] < 1 ) $captcha_config['min_length'] = 1;
    if( $captcha_config['angle_min'] < 0 ) $captcha_config['angle_min'] = 0;
    if( $captcha_config['angle_max'] > 10 ) $captcha_config['angle_max'] = 10;
    if( $captcha_config['angle_max'] < $captcha_config['angle_min'] ) $captcha_config['angle_max'] = $captcha_config['angle_min'];
    if( $captcha_config['min_font_size'] < 10 ) $captcha_config['min_font_size'] = 10;
    if( $captcha_config['max_font_size'] < $captcha_config['min_font_size'] ) $captcha_config['max_font_size'] = $captcha_config['min_font_size'];

    // Use milliseconds instead of seconds
    srand(microtime() * 100);

    // Generate CAPTCHA code if not set by user
    if( empty($captcha_config['code']) ) {
        $captcha_config['code'] = '';
        $length = rand($captcha_config['min_length'], $captcha_config['max_length']);
        while( strlen($captcha_config['code']) < $length ) {
            $captcha_config['code'] .= substr($captcha_config['characters'], rand() % (strlen($captcha_config['characters'])), 1);
        }
    }

    // Generate HTML for image src
    $image_src = substr(__FILE__, strlen( realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) )) . '?_CAPTCHA&amp;t=' . urlencode(microtime());
    $image_src = '/' . ltrim(preg_replace('/\\\\/', '/', $image_src), '/');

    $_SESSION['_CAPTCHA']['config'] = serialize($captcha_config);

    return array(
        'code' => $captcha_config['code'],
        'image_src' => $image_src
    );

}


if( !function_exists('hex2rgb') ) {
    function hex2rgb($hex_str, $return_string = false, $separator = ',') {
        $hex_str = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Fa-f]/", '', $hex_str); // Gets a proper hex string
        $rgb_array = array();
        if( strlen($hex_str) == 6 ) {
            $color_val = hexdec($hex_str);
            $rgb_array['r'] = 0xFF & ($color_val >> 0x10);
            $rgb_array['g'] = 0xFF & ($color_val >> 0x8);
            $rgb_array['b'] = 0xFF & $color_val;
        } elseif( strlen($hex_str) == 3 ) {
            $rgb_array['r'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hex_str, 0, 1), 2));
            $rgb_array['g'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hex_str, 1, 1), 2));
            $rgb_array['b'] = hexdec(str_repeat(substr($hex_str, 2, 1), 2));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $return_string ? implode($separator, $rgb_array) : $rgb_array;
    }
}

// Draw the image
if( isset($_GET['_CAPTCHA']) ) {

    session_start();


    $captcha_config = unserialize($_SESSION['_CAPTCHA']['config']);
    if( !$captcha_config ){
        exit();
    }   

    unset($_SESSION['_CAPTCHA']);

    // Use milliseconds instead of seconds
    srand(microtime() * 100);

    // Pick random background, get info, and start captcha
    $background = $captcha_config['backgrounds'][rand(0, count($captcha_config['backgrounds']) -1)];
    list($bg_width, $bg_height, $bg_type, $bg_attr) = getimagesize($background);

    $captcha = imagecreatefrompng($background);

    $color = hex2rgb($captcha_config['color']);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, $color['r'], $color['g'], $color['b']);

    // Determine text angle
    $angle = rand( $captcha_config['angle_min'], $captcha_config['angle_max'] ) * (rand(0, 1) == 1 ? -1 : 1);

    // Select font randomly
    $font = $captcha_config['fonts'][rand(0, count($captcha_config['fonts']) - 1)];

    // Verify font file exists
    if( !file_exists($font) ) throw new Exception('Font file not found: ' . $font);

    //Set the font size.
    $font_size = rand($captcha_config['min_font_size'], $captcha_config['max_font_size']);
    $text_box_size = imagettfbbox($font_size, $angle, $font, $captcha_config['code']);

    // Determine text position
    $box_width = abs($text_box_size[6] - $text_box_size[2]);
    $box_height = abs($text_box_size[5] - $text_box_size[1]);
    $text_pos_x_min = 0;
    $text_pos_x_max = ($bg_width) - ($box_width);
    $text_pos_x = rand($text_pos_x_min, $text_pos_x_max);
    $text_pos_y_min = $box_height;
    $text_pos_y_max = ($bg_height) - ($box_height / 2);
    $text_pos_y = rand($text_pos_y_min, $text_pos_y_max);

    // Draw shadow
    if( $captcha_config['shadow'] ){
        $shadow_color = hex2rgb($captcha_config['shadow_color']);
        $shadow_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, $shadow_color['r'], $shadow_color['g'], $shadow_color['b']);
        imagettftext($captcha, $font_size, $angle, $text_pos_x + $captcha_config['shadow_offset_x'], $text_pos_y + $captcha_config['shadow_offset_y'], $shadow_color, $font, $captcha_config['code']);
    }

    // Draw text
    imagettftext($captcha, $font_size, $angle, $text_pos_x, $text_pos_y, $color, $font, $captcha_config['code']);

    // Output image
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($captcha);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: We can't decipher anything, unless you show  your code in `simple-php-captcha.php`.

Comment: @Manikiran It's a page on net . I have placed the codes

Comment: Any error message from console?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd NO ,There is no error in console

Comment: Did you check Notes section from it's GIT http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/simple-php-captcha/

Comment: What is the output from `simple_php_captcha()` function?

Comment: do you have your php image extension installed and activated?

Comment: @salina: Issue resolved?